# What should I have in my prototyping toolbox?

Tags: breadboard, prototyping

I have a few bread boards, microcontrollers, resistors, LEDs and so on—the stuff I obviously need to get anything done. But I'd like to step up my prototyping game, and when it comes to choosing switches, buttons, connectors and other handy doodads, there's such an overwhelming array of options to choose from it's hard to know where to start.

What have you found to be useful in your prototyping toolbox?

Comment: No matter how much you have on hand , you usually need something when the time comes for a project.  Having the knowledge is the most important thing.  Knowing what to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

Think about the sort of projects that interest you, then get some of the devices that would be required in those projects.

A reasonable assortment of resistors and capacitors will always be useful - but some types of projects may require a different range of resistor or capacitor values than others.